# Change image on color variation not on size and show only (small thumbnail accordingly )

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

here is the link of the dummy product
http://2fitsports.com/shop/men-cycling-wears/full-sleeve-jersey/cycling-full-sleeve-jersey/

Comment: You cannot change jpg or png image color unless they are svgs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.filter-item-list[data-name="attribute_pa_color"] a').on('click', function() { 
            if(!jQuery('.filter-item-list[data-name="attribute_size"] li').hasClass("active")){
                jQuery('.filter-item-list[data-name="attribute_size"] li:nth-child(1) a').trigger("click");
            }
        });
    });
```